# Return value on try except

Tags: python

I'm writing a challenge in Python and I would like to know what is the right approach to return `None` case my function throws an Exception.

```
def get(email):
    try:
        customer = get_customer(email)
        return customer
    except TypeError as e:
        logging.error(f'Customer {email} not found', e)
```

Should I do something like `customer = None` and `return customer` after except block?

Comment: In case of exception, the default value will be returned by function which is `None`.

Comment: Your function already returns None when it catches an exception. Please clarify what you need. Are you asking whether there is a preferred style for this? Note that it is idiomatic to raise an error if you cannot provide the data requested.

Comment: @shahkalpesh but is a good practice on Python? I'm moving from Java to Python

Comment: Python functions have a default return value which is `None`. Unless there is some library which forces you to define parameter types and/or return types, you need not `return` every time.